# Changing a table to divs and then back to a table again

Tags: javascript, html, css

**[OLD AND INCORRECT: STOP DOWNVOTING]**

I have found an easy way on stackoverflow to convert tables to divs. I have classes on each of the tags example

```
<table class="table">
```

so when the div replaces it it would still have the class table. same for tbody, tr, and td.

I change the HTML with the following when the browser reaches a certain width.

```
function checkSize(){
if ($(window).width() < 768) {
    tableChanger();
}else{
    console.log("higher");
}
}

var tableChanger = function(){

$('table').each(function (){
    $(this).replaceWith( $(this).html()
        .replace(/<tbody/gi, "<div ")
        .replace(/<tr/gi, "<div ")
        .replace(/<\/tr>/gi, "</div>")
        .replace(/<td/gi, "<div")
        .replace(/<\/td>/gi, "</div>")
        .replace(/<\/tbody/gi, "<\/div")
    );
});
}
```

I would like to know if there is a way to reverse the function to create tables out of the divs? I found this very hard as obviously the closing tags are all

```
</div>
```

so a simple replace will not work.

I'm working on a responsive site (in which I had no other choice but to use tables).

Comment: it wasn't me, but you've shown no effort so that's the reason for the downvote

Comment: Probably because its not clear what you are attempting ("convert" - do you mean manually or with JS?), you don't provide a specific example in code, and you reference another SO answer without providing a link to it, so we have no idea what you found already.

Comment: I have explained that I could not do it as all the tags that changes has a closing tag of </div>. so I do not know how I would change it back to be a </table> or </tr> or </td> respectively.

Comment: Is that better? Examples edited

Comment: there is at every time another choice than tables for layout. a responsive design with tables? what an ugly idea

Answer (score 1):

You should not do this conversion.

Tables are for tabular data. Like a spreadsheet. i.e. content

`div` is for layout. i.e. make it look pretty on the screen and/or printed media

They are different concepts.

By all means use `<table>` for your tabular data. Style it with CSS for screen and/or printed media.

Besides some people/companies turn off Javascript.

Comment: I would have liked to use divs all round but ran in to trouble as we have data that needs to vertically align bottom. I can not use the display:table; styles as they dont work in IE7.

when we go to a resolution thats suited for mobile the two TD's become Divs with a width of 100% to fill the screen. that is where the issue comes in.

Comment: @Gezzasa - Back in the old days (now I am showing my age) everything was HTML - we had to use tables then. Not the whole idea is HTML is for content, CSS is for styling. So just have a CSS for PCs, Mobiles, People who are visually impaired. Add a dash of PHP to deliver the page with the appropriate verison of CSS. You can even use inheritance on that front so just change that front to just tweak the style as necessary.